# C#.NET Core - Dapper - Multi-Join-Mapping (all separate [A]s with related [B]s)

Tags: c#, .net-core, mapping, inner-join, dapper

I'm relatively young in .NET Core and totally new in using Dapper. But I've some skills in C# *(1-2 years)*. My first project I need to start with dapper and the mapping there.

SQL tables:

[image: SQL-Tables]

Table [A] content:

```
id:                                     name:
---                                     -----
F3613B62-EEB5-4B27-9A20-4038F60B25BD    name-01-of-a
6A68ED79-5605-43B4-9F70-675CAF3C5C65    name-02-of-a
76CB90D6-93BE-452E-8A72-F525180B77E8    name-03-of-a
```

Table [AB] content:

```
A_id:                                   B_id:
-----                                   -----
F3613B62-EEB5-4B27-9A20-4038F60B25BD    19C592B1-4D4C-4660-9D1D-C5C4AA1F296C
F3613B62-EEB5-4B27-9A20-4038F60B25BD    C71E6490-2410-4FA3-A4D0-F24B8207B67A
6A68ED79-5605-43B4-9F70-675CAF3C5C65    D763F490-A6B6-4FCB-A3BA-755A44E16D6F
6A68ED79-5605-43B4-9F70-675CAF3C5C65    19C592B1-4D4C-4660-9D1D-C5C4AA1F296C
76CB90D6-93BE-452E-8A72-F525180B77E8    D763F490-A6B6-4FCB-A3BA-755A44E16D6F
76CB90D6-93BE-452E-8A72-F525180B77E8    19C592B1-4D4C-4660-9D1D-C5C4AA1F296C
76CB90D6-93BE-452E-8A72-F525180B77E8    C71E6490-2410-4FA3-A4D0-F24B8207B67A
```

Table [B] content:

```
id:                                     name:
---                                     -----
19C592B1-4D4C-4660-9D1D-C5C4AA1F296C    name-01-of-b
C71E6490-2410-4FA3-A4D0-F24B8207B67A    name-02-of-b
D763F490-A6B6-4FCB-A3BA-755A44E16D6F    name-03-of-b
```

**AEntity:**

```cs
public class AEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AEntity> A { get; set; } = null;
}
```

**BEntity:**

```cs
public class B
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Single join request:

```cs
public async Task<AEntity> GetById(Guid id)
{
    using (var connection = Connection)
    {
        var list = new List<BEntity>();
        return (await connection.QueryAsync<AEntity, BEntity, AEntity>(sql: $"SELECT a.*, b.* FROM ab INNER JOIN a ON a.id = ab.a_id INNER JOIN b ON b.id = ab.b_id WHERE a.id=@id",
                map: (a, b) => {
                     list.Add(b);
                     a.B = list;
                     return a;
                },
                param: new { id } 
        )).AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

That's really simple. There is a relation table **[AB]** and a table **[A]** and another table **[B]**.

*(For example the table **[A]** could be **[MOVIES]** and table **[B]** could be **[ACTORS]**)*

So one actor plays in several movies. But also several actors play in one movie. *(**n : n**)*

The GetById (single entity) does work, but I need an **GetAll (all entities)** as an IEnumerable collection... It should be the same mapping: content of **[B]** as a collection of all (3) **[A]** in the corresponding `IEnumerable` field of the **[A]** object. So that we get that three **[A]** objects:

Desired output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "F3613B62-EEB5-4B27-9A20-4038F60B25BD",
    "name": "name-01-of-a",
    "b": [
      {
        "id": "19C592B1-4D4C-4660-9D1D-C5C4AA1F296C",
        "name": "name-01-of-b"
      },
      {
        "id": "C71E6490-2410-4FA3-A4D0-F24B8207B67A",
        "name": "name-02-of-b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "6A68ED79-5605-43B4-9F70-675CAF3C5C65",
    "name": "name-02-of-a",
    "b": [
      {
        "id": "D763F490-A6B6-4FCB-A3BA-755A44E16D6F",
        "name": "name-03-of-b"
      },
      {
        "id": "19C592B1-4D4C-4660-9D1D-C5C4AA1F296C",
        "name": "name-01-of-b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "76CB90D6-93BE-452E-8A72-F525180B77E8",
    "name": "name-03-of-a",
    "b": [
      {
        "id": "D763F490-A6B6-4FCB-A3BA-755A44E16D6F",
        "name": "name-03-of-b"
      },
      {
        "id": "19C592B1-4D4C-4660-9D1D-C5C4AA1F296C",
        "name": "name-01-of-b"
      },
      {
        "id": "C71E6490-2410-4FA3-A4D0-F24B8207B67A",
        "name": "name-02-of-b"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

All join request:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<AEntity>> GetById(Guid id)
{
  using (var connection = Connection)
  {
    var list = new List<BEntity>();
    var aId = new Guid();
    return (await connection.QueryAsync<AEntity, BEntity, AEntity>(
      sql: $"SELECT a.*, b.* FROM ab INNER JOIN a ON a.id = ab.a_id INNER JOIN b ON b.id = ab.b_id",
      map: (a, b) => {
        if (aId != a.Id)
        {
          aId = a.Id;
          list.Clear();                    
        }
        list.Add(b);
        a.B = list;
        return a;
      },
      param: new {
        id
      }
    )).AsQueryable();
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work. :( I get 7x **[A]** with each 3x **[B]**. :/

Thanks for every help. :)

Answer (score 0):

### **AEntity:**

```cs
public class AEntity
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ISet<AEntity> A { get; set; } = null;
}
```

### **Single-Join-Request:**

```cs
public async Task<AEntity> GetById(Guid id)
{
  using (var connection = Connection)
  {
    var as= new Dictionary<Guid, BEntity>();
    return (await connection.QueryAsync<AEntity, BEntity, AEntity>(
      sql: $"SELECT a.*, b.* FROM ab INNER JOIN a ON a.id = ab.a_id INNER JOIN b ON b.id = ab.b_id WHERE a.id=@id",
      map: (a, b) => {
        if (!as.TryGetValue(a.Id, out var entity))
        {
          entity = a;
          entity.B= new HashSet<b>();
          as.Add(a.Id, entity);
        }
        entity.B.Add(b);
        return entity;
      },
      param: new {
        id
      }
    )).FirstOrDefault();
  }
}
```

### **All-Join-Request:**

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<AEntity>> GetById(Guid id)
{
  using (var connection = Connection)
  {
    var as= new Dictionary<Guid, BEntity>();
    return (await connection.QueryAsync<AEntity, BEntity, AEntity>(
      sql: $"SELECT a.*, b.* FROM ab INNER JOIN a ON a.id = ab.a_id INNER JOIN b ON b.id = ab.b_id",
      map: (a, b) => {
        if (!as.TryGetValue(a.Id, out var entity))
        {
          entity = a;
          entity.B= new HashSet<b>();
          as.Add(a.Id, entity);
        }
        entity.B.Add(b);
        return entity;
      },
      param: new {
        id
      }
    )).Distinct();
  }
}
```

### **(All-Join-Request) returned tupel / object:**

```json
[
  {
    "id": "F3613B62-EEB5-4B27-9A20-4038F60B25BD",
    "name": "name-01-of-a",
    "b": [
      {
        "id": "19C592B1-4D4C-4660-9D1D-C5C4AA1F296C",
        "name": "name-01-of-b"
      },
      {
        "id": "C71E6490-2410-4FA3-A4D0-F24B8207B67A",
        "name": "name-02-of-b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "6A68ED79-5605-43B4-9F70-675CAF3C5C65",
    "name": "name-02-of-a",
    "b": [
      {
        "id": "D763F490-A6B6-4FCB-A3BA-755A44E16D6F",
        "name": "name-03-of-b"
      },
      {
        "id": "19C592B1-4D4C-4660-9D1D-C5C4AA1F296C",
        "name": "name-01-of-b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "76CB90D6-93BE-452E-8A72-F525180B77E8",
    "name": "name-03-of-a",
    "b": [
      {
        "id": "D763F490-A6B6-4FCB-A3BA-755A44E16D6F",
        "name": "name-03-of-b"
      },
      {
        "id": "19C592B1-4D4C-4660-9D1D-C5C4AA1F296C",
        "name": "name-01-of-b"
      },
      {
        "id": "C71E6490-2410-4FA3-A4D0-F24B8207B67A",
        "name": "name-02-of-b"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now the stuff works fine. I just used a simple **helper-dictionary** to buffer the separate Bs into the right As. And I changed the **IEnumerable** to a ISet (HashSet), because the .Add()-Method. :)

Hope somebody can use my solution.